# How can get id for category from autocomplate

Tags: php, ajax

i have input type that can any user insert category name, here when user type category i need to get with category name the ID for this category and put it in another text type hidden

my ajax code for autocomplate :-

```
$("#txtCompanyCat").autocomplete("get_cat_list.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: true,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
});
```

and get_cat_list.php code :-

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(file_exists('select.php'))
{
    require_once('function/connect.php');
    $connect = new connect();

$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Category_name FROM category where 
            Category_delete ='0' and Category_name LIKE '%$q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['Category_name'];
    echo "$cname\n";
}
}
?>
```

here i get category name and insert it into :-

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearchCat" class="class_input tooltip_s" name="txtSearchCat" placeholder="Type category ..." title="Type category" >
```

i need category ID, how can get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
     $cname = $rs['Category_name'];
     $cid = $rs['Category_id'];
      echo "$cname|$cid\n";
     }
```

and

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(document).ready(function(){
 var url2='get_cat_list.php';   ////here is path for your file


                                $j('#txtSearchCat').autocomplete(url2, {
                                width: 278,
                                matchContains: true,
                                selectFirst: false
                                });
                             $j("#txtSearchCat").result(function(event, data, formatted) {

                        $j("#txtSearchCatID").val(data[1]);

                });

            });
```

to store id in hidden field

Comment: where can i put this `$("#hidden_id").val(data[1]);`

Comment: i try but show me this error on firebug:-

`ReferenceError: data is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$("#txtSearchCatID").val(data[1]);`

Comment: this is same line wt i wrote....$j("#txtSearchCat").result(function(event, data, formatted)....check...here data is define

Comment: `<input id="txtSearchCatID" type="hidden" value="" name="txtSearchCatID">`

Comment: in ....data[1] you will get id ....see this line...echo "$cname|$cid\n";.....$cid is come in $data[1]....